# Always up header and sliding div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Suppose to have an header which is always visible (i.e. also when page is scrolled down).

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logindiv">
        Something to show for login purpose
    </div>
    My title etc.
</div>
<div id="pagecontent">
    page content and also a <button id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

The CSS is something similar:

```
 #logindiv{
    width: 100%;  
    display:none;
 }
 #header{
    display:block;
    z-index: 1000;
    height:50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%  
 }
 #pagecontent{
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top:50px;
    width: 100%  
 }
```

The div **logindiv** is shown with jQuery when on click on such a button: a **slideDown()** function is used for cosmetic purpose.

How can I also *slide-down* the **pagecontent** div by the same height of **logindiv**?
Of course, I also have to reset everything after the *slide-up* of the hidden div.

See my working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds6qT/).
Moreover, see [this site](http://www.yoox.com) for an example of the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, the question was not explicit. I hope it's better now! Thanks

Comment: @JeanValjean. Sorry I got you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **a** solution. Here you can find the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds6qT/15/).

1) I **added an empty div** before the pagecontent.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logindiv">
        Someting to show for login purpose
    </div>
    My title etc.
</div>
<div id="forsliding"></div>
<div id="pagecontent">
    page content and also a <button id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

2) I modified the CSS by adding the CSS for the new div, that is equal to the CSS for the sliding div. Of course **I had to set the height fixed**.

```
 #logindiv, #forsliding{
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;   
    display:none;
 }
```

3) And I did a **small change to the Javascript** code.

```
$(function () {
   $('#btn').click(function(){
       var div =  $('#logindiv');
       if(div.is(':hidden'))
         div.add('#forsliding').slideDown();
       else
         div.add('#forsliding').slideUp();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something easier - put both divs in a container div, and slide the container:

```
<div id="slide-me-instead">  <!-- Work with this -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logindiv">
            Someting to show for login purpose
        </div>
        My title etc.
    </div>
    <div id="pagecontent">
        page content and also a <button id="btn">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But in this case I will not slidedown() the div "logindiv". I will slidedown everything. Maybe I didn't undestood. Can you please provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Measure the height of visible #logindiv, and when #btn is clicked, .animate the #pagecontent margin-top plus it's original margin top, along with logindiv .slidedown()

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P8LRT/)

**CODE**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var div =  $('#logindiv')
            var div2=$('#pagecontent')
            var div3=$('#header')
        if(div.is(':hidden'))
            {  div.slideDown();
        div2.css('margin-top',parseInt(div2.css('margin-top'))+ $('#header').height()+'px').hide().show('slow')} 
            else {
          div.slideUp();
        div2.css('margin-top',parseInt(div2.css('margin-top'))- $('#header').height()+'px').hide().show('slow')
    }

    });
});​
```

**EDIT**

WITHOUT ANimation

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var div =  $('#logindiv')
            var div2=$('#pagecontent')
            var div3=$('#header')
        if(div.is(':hidden'))
            {  div.slideDown();
        div2.css('margin-top',parseInt(div2.css('margin-top'))+ $('#header').height()+'px')} 
            else {
          div.slideUp();
        div2.css('margin-top',parseInt(div2.css('margin-top'))- $('#header').height()+'px')
    }

    });
});​
```

Comment: By looking at your jsfiddle, seems that the pagecontent disappear and then appear with the slide down. I modified your css to highlight the problem: look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P8LRT/1/)

Comment: i just added on easing by first hiding it and showing it. you can remove .hide() and it will work fine..

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/P8LRT/2/) is the JSFiddle obtained by applying your changes. Look at my solution/trick, it seems to work better: I can use the slideDown/Up in that way!